# how to fix tmux keybinding? (after upgrading to 3.0a)

Tags: tmux

I was previously using tmux in Kubuntu 19.10 (where my keybinding worked) and just upgraded to Kubuntu 20.04 (where the binding no longer works).  I don't know the previous tmux version but currently it's `tmux 3.0a`.

The broken keybinding is: `bind-key \ split-window -h -c '#{pane_current_path}'`.  I can manually invoke `split-window -h -c '#{pane_current_path}'` to create the new pane, but that's nearly impossible to remember&type.

The similar keybinding: `bind-key - split-window -v -c '#{pane_current_path}'` still works.  And all my other config seems to still be working.

I've tried `bind-key -n \ split-window...` guessing that the `-n` argument might help, but it did not.  I don't know any other possibilities to try, or how to troubleshoot/debug this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to escape the backslash, or quote it:

```
bind-key \\ split-window -h -c '#{pane_current_path}'
```

or

```
bind-key '\' split-window -h -c '#{pane_current_path}'
```

... otherwise you get an error:

> `unknown key:  split-window`

The error comes from `tmux` trying to assign a command to the key  `split-window` (note the initial space, which you added there by escaping it with `\`).

Comment: I wish I could vote for this multiple times to express an appropriate level of gratitude <3